# SparkFatalException root cause

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 3.0.2 with java 8 version.
I am trying to write data on s3 path using spark job.

I am getting below exception, not able to know what caused this error. Any clue what went wrong and what could be the solution ?

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.spark.util.SparkFatalException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:515)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1(SparkPlan.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenInner(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SerializeFromObjectExec.consume(objects.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SerializeFromObjectExec.doConsume(objects.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.constructDoConsumeFunction(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.doProduce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SerializeFromObjectExec.doProduce(objects.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SerializeFromObjectExec.produce(objects.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doProduce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.produce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.doProduceWithKeys(HashAggregateExec.scala:754)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.doProduce(HashAggregateExec.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.produce(HashAggregateExec.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:692)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.inputRDD(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.shuffleDependency$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.shuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.util.SparkFatalException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.$anonfun$relationFuture$1(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

not able to know what caused this error. Any clue what went wrong and what could be the solution ?

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz  any clue?

Comment: @DaRkMaN can you help me